# Solve "Missing required parameters for [Route: post.show] [URI: post/show/{id}]."

Tags: php, laravel-5

Basically, I want to solve this error

> Missing required parameters for [Route: post.show] [URI: post/show/{id}]. (View: C:\xampp2\htdocs\galaxall\resources\views\index.blade.php)

I am trying to make a system on my site whereby users can post,view post comment on posts and reply.

When a usertypes the details of his post in `http://localhost:8000/post/create`,it is supposed to accept the values,insert it into the database and redirect to `http://localhost:8000/posts/show` and show a the list of posts ever 'posted' so that the user can view a post can comment and reply to comments about that post.

BUT 
what currently happens is that after typing the details for the to-be post in 
`http://localhost:8000/post/create`,it inserts into the db and then shows this error on laravel 'customised' error page:

> Missing required parameters for [Route: post.show] [URI: post/show/{id}]. (View: C:\xampp2\htdocs\galaxall\resources\views\index.blade.php)

I have no clue what I'm doing wrong.

Please help

These are my code:

**PostController.php**

```
    <?php

// PostController.php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use Stevebauman\Location\Facades\Location;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'Uploader',
        ];

    public function __construct()
    {
        return $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('post');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        {


            $post =  new Post;

            $post->title = $request->get('title');
            $post->type = $request->get('type');
            $post->description = $request->get('description');
            $post->body = $request->get('body');
            $post->UniqueId = str_random(16);
            $post->Uploader = Auth::user()->name;
            $post->Language = 'en';
            $post->Location=Location::get()->countryCode;            
            $post->views = 0;
            $post->Applauds = 0;
            $post->Boos = 0;
            $post->Tags =  "hey";

                         if ($request->get('agegroup')) {
                            $post->agegroup = $request->get('agegroup');
                         } else {
                            $post->agegroup ='undefined';
                         }

            $post->AllowComments = 'true';
            $post->CommentsBg = 'default';
            $post->Visibility = 'globally public';
            $post->others = 'embeddable';


            $post->save();

            return redirect('posts');

        }
    }

   public function index()
   {
    $posts = Post::all();

    return view('index', compact('posts'));
   }

   public function show($id)
   {
    $post = Post::find($id);

    return view('show', compact('post'));
   }
}
```

**CommentController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Comment;
use App\Post;

class CommentController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $comment = new Comment;
        $comment->body = $request->get('comment_body');
        $comment->user()->associate($request->user());
        $post = Post::find($request->get('post_id'));
        $post->comments()->save($comment);

        return back();
    }
}
```

**Web.php**

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();


Route::get('logout', '\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin');
Route::get('/upload', 'UploadController@index')->name('upload');

Route::get('/post/create', 'PostController@create')->name('post.create');
Route::post('/post/store', 'PostController@store')->name('post.store');

Route::get('/posts', 'PostController@index')->name('posts');
Route::get('/post/show/{id}', 'PostController@show')->name('post.show');

Route::post('/comment/store', 'CommentController@store')->name('comment.add');
Route::post('/reply/store', 'CommentController@replyStore')->name('reply.add');

Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'imageupload', 'ImageController@Image');
Route::delete('delimage/{filename}', 'ImageController@Image');
```

**post.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Create Post</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="post" action="{{ route('post.store') }}">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @csrf
                            <label class="label">Post Title: </label>
                            <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" required/>
                        </div>
                        <label class="label">Post Type </label>
                        <input type="text" name="type" class="form-control" required/>

                         <label class="label">Tags </label>
                        <input type="text" name="tags" class="form-control" required/>

                        <label class="label">Age-group(optional) </label>
                        <input type="text" name="agegroup" class="form-control" required/>


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="label">Post Description </label>
                            <textarea name="description" rows="5" cols="20" class="form-control" required></textarea>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="label">Post Body: </label>
                            <textarea name="body" rows="10" cols="30" class="form-control" required></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

**show.blade.php**

```
<!-- show.blade.php -->

@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p><b>{{ $post->title }}</b></p>
                    <p>
                        {{ $post->body }}
                    </p>
                    <hr />
                    <h4>Display Comments</h4>
                    @foreach($post->comments as $comment)
                        <div class="display-comment">
                            <strong>{{ $comment->user->name }}</strong>
                            <p>{{ $comment->body }}</p>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                    <hr />
                    <h4>Add comment</h4>
                    <form method="post" action="{{ route('comment.add') }}">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="comment_body" class="form-control" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{{ $post->id }}" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value="Add Comment" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach($posts as $post)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $post->id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $post->title }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="{{ route('post.show', $post->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Show Post</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
                </tbody>

            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter of the `route` function should be an array of parameter name to value pairs, eg

```html
<a href="{{ route('post.show', ['id' => $post]) }}" class="btn btn-primary">
  Show Post
</a>
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/urls#urls-for-named-routes

Comment: When I click on the links,for example,the first row, of `index.blade.php`,it is meant to direct me to `http://localhost:8000/post/show/1` but it leads me to `http://localhost:8000/posts/show/` have any Idea why?

Comment: Do you have `['id' => $post]`, `['id' => $post->id]` or`['id' => $post->Id]` in your route function? The docs say you can just use `$post` like I have in my answer so you don't have to worry about what field is the primary key

Comment: I'm sorry...which route function?

Comment: The one in your template, ie the one in my answer

Comment: That's what I thought. Note the syntax in my answer, you can just use `['id' => $post]` according to the documentation